What is the original English title of this documentary?
I have this documentary voiced-over in French named "Survivre l'Apocalypse" and I can't find the original English version of it.



I was hesitating but I got advised to ask this here. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259460/210483 )

@AnkitSharma Is it me only or the Youtube link doesn't display?

Video is showing to me in firefox , must be a plugin issue to you.

@AnkitSharma Well that's odd then… (For the record, I'm using Palemoon, based on an older version of Firefox but some basic debugging doesn't give me much info. It does work under Chrome)

To me its completely opposite :) I think on main meta people can support u better on video embedding issues.

@AnkitSharma Well I don't need to see it personally. :) More like the people that can actually help me.

It's called After Armageddon; it's a docudrama produced by Raw Television and aired on the History Channel back in 2010.




Great! May I ask how you found it? The credits at the end of the video didn't help me enough personally.

at 1:27:37, there's a credit that says it was produced by Raw TV, copyrighted by A&E networks (which owns The History Channel) ... Google did the rest (admittedly, there were a few such productions, so I had to watch clips of them to get the right one).
